# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 341424000 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 78MB until OOM

Tags: java, android

I got this error everytime i wanna encode a video's bytes with Base64 into string, I assume that the video size is too big to encode because when I tried to encode a smaller video, it worked fine.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 341424000 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 78MB until OOM, target footprint 479725424, growth limit 536870912
```

And this is my code:

```java
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 200) {
                Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();
                String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE };
                Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedMediaUri, columns, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int pathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex( columns[0] );
                String contentPath = cursor.getString(pathColumnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                FileInputStream inputStream;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(contentPath);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail to retrieve video data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                byte[] bytes;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bytes = output.toByteArray();
                Client.videoData = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
        }
    }
```

Im trying to read a video file in bytes and then convert it into string with Base64. But it just keep giving me this error

(Note: I will have decode it back to bytes and set it in videoview later)

So how can I fix this? Please help!

Comment: Why would you base64 encode that file? Bad idea.

Comment: @blackapps uhh, this is because I want to send it to the server in string

Comment: You don't say anything in detail about sending to the server, but there is no problem with treating base64 streamwise. You do not need to load the whole base64 string into memory.

Comment: Why do you want to send a big file in a string that is 30% more bytes then the file contains? Why not send the file directly,?

Comment: Assuming you even need to encode the data in base64, you should use `Base64.Encoder.wrap` while streaming directly to the server, instead of converting it in memory first.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely able to be fixed by starting your program binaries on its command line with flags for memory assignment to the JVM of -Xss -Xmx  -Xms and also assign a G1 garbage collector.
In X32 the quantity of RAM is limited but in X64 the RAM assignable is much larger.

The way you need to encode base64 in Android is use small amounts of memory a time by processing the bytes 3 at a time for encoding and 4 bytes a routine call of method for unencode.
Android has a GC but I am not an android dev but it is a recommendation from this android dev page generally. e.g. to avoid memory churn 300 bytes each method call in the loop stopping short of any .3 or .6 tail by file size calc division.see after the link.
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory
java.util.Base64 **encoder** has withoutPadding() method. As I said, you loop over the file bytes in multiples of 3 to encode, just divide file size by 3 with double type math and convert answer toString() and string.indexof ".3" one leftover or".6" two leftover bytes and call encode with the method that pads normally on those remainders. It does not have a tail pad for exact multiples of 3 with encode.

Comment: but how do i do that in android studio? Could you please tell me the instruction?

Comment: I don't think the version I have here was quite finished when this was answered.  See StreamB64UnitisedByteRead interface.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q00-bhfgwrmE9fLqFrXvjGCE5JWKnf3A/view?usp=drivesdk